# Syncing Larvel Debugbar to Vue's UI

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

We are making an axios call that pulls in a gigantic object which is used to render a very lengthy UI using Bootstrap Vue.

The issue is that the UI continues to be rendered well after the axios call has been received.

Is there a way to check if everything is done rendering in Vue? The mounted hook does not work here.

---

More context:

The Laravel Debugbar gives me the best feedback here. When #6 AJAX is done, I know that the UI is done rendering. But how I can sync Laraven's debugbar with Vue's hooks?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijRgv.gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe to try with `this.$nextTick` inside [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) hook

Answer (score 0):

There is another lifecycle hook in vue beside `mounted`

The [updated](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#updated) lifecycle hook is fired everytime a component reactive property changes and the virtual dom is updated.

To react to virtual dom changes inside the updated hook you can use `nextTick()`

Comment: yeah actually it does work (i had to use it in the child component that renders the accordion), however, there are multiple updates and its going to be interested to pinpoint to #6